# Network Error with Axios: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (React-Springboot-Spring Security)

Tags: reactjs, redirect, axios

I'm very new in react, I set up springboot with spring security as my backend and is trying to do a simple GetMapping from my frontend using React. I have spring security implemented on my backend, so I first use a Login component from React to retrieve a JWT token and put it into local storage (bad practice, but this is just for practice), and then once the token is in the local storage, the Login page goes to the HomePage where axios requests a GetMapping. I have another component that adds the token to the header of each request.

when I put everything into Postman, it works. The login authentication PostMapping returns a token, the token with the GetMapping returns data.

I'm getting a net:ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS once it goes to the HomePage that i really don't understand...

Without implementing the security part, the Homepage does display data.

this is the login paget to get JWT token

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function LoginPage() {

  let navigate = useNavigate(); 

  const [user, setUsers] = useState({
    username:"",
    password:""
  }); 

  const onInputChange = (e) =>{
    setUsers({...user, [e.target.name]:e.target.value});
  }; 

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8082/api/v1/auth/signin", user);
      const { token } = response.data;

      localStorage.setItem('token', token);

    } catch (error) {
   }
  };

  return (
       
    <div className='container'>   {/*make a container*/}
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-md-6 offset-md-3 border rounded p-4 mt-2 shadow'>
          <h2 className='text-center m-4'> HRMasery Login</h2>         {/*container title*/}

          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>      {/*when submit -> trigger onSubmit function */}
          <div className='mb-3'>
            <label htmlFor="Name" className='form-label'> {/*for label */}
              UserName
            </label>

            {/*when user inputs, type string, assigned to name*/}
            <input        
            type={"text"}
            name="username"
            className='form-control'
            value={user.username}
            onChange={onInputChange}
            placeholder='Enter Username'
            >
            </input>
          </div>

          <div className='mb-3'>
            <label htmlFor="jobTitle" className='form-label'>
              Password
            </label>
            <input
            type={"text"}
            name="password"
            className='form-control'
            value={user.password}
            onChange={onInputChange}
            placeholder='Password'
            >
            </input>
          </div>

          <Link type='submit' className='bnt btn-outline-primary' to={'/homepage'}>   {/*submit button is submit class */}
            Login 
          </Link>

          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

this is the component to add jwt to header:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8082',
});

// Add a request interceptor
api.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);

export default api
```

this is the HomePage with the GetMapping:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link, useParams} from "react-router-dom"; 
import Navbar from '../Layout/Navbar';
import api from '../api'; 

export default function HomePage_Manager() {

    const[users, setUsers] = useState([])

    let JWT = localStorage.getItem('token');

    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchProfile = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await api.get('/allemployee');
          setUsers(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
        }
      };
  
      fetchProfile();
    }, []);


  return (

    <div className='container'>  
    
        <div className='py-4'>
        <table className="table border shadow"> {/*make table inside the container*/}
  <thead>
    <tr>              {/*colum names inside the table*/}
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">PhoneNumber</th>
      <th scope="col">Job Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Annual Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
        {users.map((user, index) => (
            <tr>
            <th scope="row" key={index}> {index+1} </th>
            <td>{user.id}</td>
            <td>{user.name}</td>
            <td>{user.email}</td>
            <td>{user.phoneNumber}</td>
            <td>{user.jobTitle}</td>
            <td>${user.annualSalary}</td>

            <td>
                <Link className='btn btn-primary mx-2'
                to={`/viewstaff/${user.id}`}>
                    View Employee
                </Link>

                <Link className='btn btn-outline-primary mx-2'
                to={`/editstaff/${user.id}`}>
                    Edit Employee
                </Link>
                
            </td>

          </tr>
        ))
    }

  </tbody>
</table>
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```